# AWS SQS queue sending messages directly to Dead Letter Queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

Did any one notice issue while consuming large number of messages from SQS Queues using spring boot listener. Some of the messages are going directly to Dead Letter Queue.

The messages in the Dead Letter Queue show the MessageDeliveryCount as `6`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the visibilityTimeout attribute in DLQ. When processing time exceeds this, messages will move to DLQ